# Is there a way to reuse Bootstrap's OverlayTrigger component?

Tags: reactjs, performance, optimization, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have hundreds of objects rendered on the screen that are each wrapped in a `<OverlayTrigger>`  (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#overlaytrigger)

If these OverlayTriggers are displaying the same/similar text, is there a way I can just instantiate one and reuse that one, instead of rendering hundreds for each object that remain inactive until they're clicked/hovered over?

Answer (score 1):

If you were able to use [Overlay](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#overlay) instead of `OverlayTrigger` you could do this by adding event handlers to the components that you want to trigger the overlay (e.g. `onClick`, `onMouseOver/onMouseOut`). The event handler would:

1. update the trigger to be the element that triggered the overlay (so the overlay is displayed alongside the element)
2. update the `show` state to ensure the overlay is displayed

The HTML would allow you to define a single `Overlay` element that can be used by multiple objects (in this case 4 buttons):

```
<div>
  <Overlay target={target.current} show={show} placement="right">
    <Tooltip id="button-tooltip">Simple tooltip</Tooltip>
  </Overlay>

  <Button onMouseOver={showOverlay} onMouseOut={showOverlay}>
    Test
  </Button>
  <Button onMouseOver={showOverlay} onMouseOut={showOverlay}>
    Test 2
  </Button>
  <Button onMouseOver={showOverlay} onMouseOut={showOverlay}>
    Test 3
  </Button>
  <Button onMouseOver={showOverlay} onMouseOut={showOverlay}>
    Test 4
  </Button>
</div>
```

The `show` state and `target` ref would need to be introduced:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false); // Used to display the overlay
const target = useRef(null); // Used to store the reference to the HTML element that triggered the overlay
```

The `showOverlay` function would set the target ref to the HTML element that was clicked/hovered over, then set the flag to display the Overlay:

```
const showOverlay = (e) => {
  target.current = e.target;
  setShow(!show);
};
```

There's a working demo of this [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-zeh-wt53n?file=/src/App.js).